# shellshock solution for nexenta/solaris

Tags: bash, apt, solaris, shellshock, nexenta

I'm trying to solve the shellshock issue on my system:

```
SunOS localhost 5.11 NexentaOS_134f i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris

# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.11)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Has anybody fixed it for nexenta?
How can I find the correct patch?
Tried apt-get, but I can't find an active, updated repository.

I'm ok with downloading patches and compiling them, just don't really know where to download nexenta packages from...

Comment: For Solaris, [Oracle published patches on their support portal](https://blogs.oracle.com/security/entry/security_alert_cve_2014_7169).

Comment: Can it be downloaded without a support user? anyway, I found a p5i package, but I can't open it. I got no `pkg` or `packagemanager` commands. Is there anywhere I can download recent bash source code from..?

Comment: ok. simpler than i thought.
dowloaded source from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ and applied patches...

Comment: how did you patch bash from sources?

Comment: With the `patch -p0` command. You got to have 2 directories: bash source directory and bash patches directory. cd to the source dir and patch every patch file. You can see the text in the patch files - the directories usage is easy to see

Comment: forgot to mention that after applying patches to the source, run `./configure`, then `make` and `make install`. And then you have latest bash

Answer (score 2):

I got my system updated by downloading 4.3 bash source code and patches from ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash and compiling it to replace the existing code. It works, now waiting for more patches.